# how to avoid creating a slug that already exists as a Route "Symfony 4"

Tags: php, validation, routes, symfony4, slug

I have the entity Page identified by slug. Also I have the action to view a page in the Page controler :

```
class PageController extends AbstractController
{
   /**
    * @Route("/{slug}", name="fronend_page")
    */
   public function show(Page $page)
   {
       return $this->render("font_end/page/show.html.twig", [
           "page" => $page,
       ]);
   }
}
```

I am looking for good practice to validate the slug ( check if exist in routes) before save it in the database without use prefixes
Example :

route exist : `@route ("/blog")`

check if blog exist before create slug : `/{slug} = /blog`

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UniqueEntity` annotation for checking slug for unique.

For example, in your entity add `UniqueEntity` annotation with the `slug` field.

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity("slug")
 */
class Page
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $slug;

    public function __construct(string $slug)
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;
    }
}
```

Then you can create some service or do validation in your controller.

```
   /**
    * @Route("/{slug}")
    */
   public function show($slug, ValidatorInterface $validator)
   {
       $page = new Page($slug);
       $errors = $validator->validate($author);

       if (count($errors) > 0) {
           // handle errors
       }

       // save entity 
   }
```

**Update:**

For checking already existing routes probably you can do something like this

```
public function isRouteExist(string $slug): bool
{
    /** @var Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface $router */
    $routes = array_filter(array_map(function (\Symfony\Component\Routing\Route $route) {
        if (!$route->compile()->getVariables()) {
            return $route->getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }, $router->getRouteCollection()->all()));

    return in_array(sprintf('/%s', $slug), $routes, true);
}
```

Comment: thanks **Ihor**, but i want to check slug with **Routes** existing not with slug

Comment: Suppose we have route : Route("/blog")
and we have a system of pages with route : Route("/{slug}")
When creating a page ,There is a possibility that they have the same name "Blog" . 
I am looking for a way to check slug with route existing

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I created a validation Symfony  :

```
class ContainsCheckSlugValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{

   private $router;

   public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router)
   {
       $this->router = $router;
   }

   public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
   {
       if (!$constraint instanceof ContainsCheckSlug) {
           throw new UnexpectedTypeException($constraint, ContainsCheckSlug::class);
       }

       // custom constraints should ignore null and empty values to allow
       // other constraints (NotBlank, NotNull, etc.) take care of that
       if (null === $value || "" === $value) {
           return;
       }
       $routes = $this->router->getRouteCollection()->all();
       $routes = array_map(function($route){
           return $route->getPath();
       },$routes);
       if (in_array(sprintf("/{_locale}/%s/", $value), $routes, true)) {
           $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
               ->setParameter("{{ string }}", $value)
               ->addViolation();
       }
   }
}
```

Thanks @Ihor_Kostrov :)